How to fix access issues when trying to access VS code Via Azure Ai Studio project
We are facing an issue when access the Azure AI Studio Compute from a windows machine. When the compute is ready and we try to access it via VScode Desktop we are seeing the following error message: On the portal the

Here are my extensions from Vscode:

The issue is only occurring on the Windows machine, when accessing from Mac machine the issue does not occur. The Compute instance is up and running but when trying to open the vscode it errors. Any solutions on this

